# How to use dtutil to migrate SSIS packages when SSISDB is used instead of MSDB?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-2016, ssis-projects

I'm trying to use *dtutil* to automate the migration of hundreds of packages from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2019 in another server.

[image: Source database structure]

It seems *dtutil* is unable to find the project/package folder.

All I found in docs and links seems to refer to msdb, but here, the folder/project/package data is stored in SSISDB database tables instead.

[image: dtutil error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### I don't think you can use DTUtil to migrate packages from SSISDB.

Based on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/dtutil-utility?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The dtutil command prompt utility is used to manage SQL Server Integration Services packages. The utility can copy, move, delete, or verify the existence of a package. **These actions can be performed on any SSIS package that is stored in one of three locations: a Microsoft SQL Server database, the SSIS Package Store, and the file system**.

#### Alternatives

There are several alternatives to migrate SSIS projects from SSISDB to another instance such as backup and restoring the SSISDB database, using a third-party solution, or using the Package import wizard.

You can refer to the following articles for more information:

- [Moving the SSISDB Catalog on a new SQL Server instance](https://www.sqlshack.com/moving-the-ssisdb-catalog-on-a-new-sql-server-instance/)
- [Upgrade and Migrate SSIS Catalog and SSISDB to a New Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6831/how-to-migrate-ssisdb-to-another-server/)

Comment: Correct! Thank you!